# Map multiple source fields to same type target fields with Mapstruct

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

Consider the following POJOs:

```
public class SchedulePayload {
    public String name;
    public String scheduler;
    public PeriodPayload notificationPeriod;
    public PeriodPayload schedulePeriod;
}

private class Lecture {
    public ZonedDateTime start;
    public ZonedDateTime end;
}

public class XmlSchedule {
    public String scheduleName;
    public String schedulerName;
    public DateTime notificationFrom;
    public DateTime notificationTo;
    public DateTime scheduleFrom;
    public DateTime scheduleTo;
}

public class PeriodPayload {
    public DateTime start;
    public DateTime finish;
}
```

Using MapStruct, I created a mapper that maps `XmlSchedule` to a `SchedulePayload`. Due to "business" "logic", I need to constrain `notificationPeriod` and `schedulePeriod` to a `Lecture`'s `start` and `end` field values. Here is what I've come up to, using another class:

```
@Mapper(imports = { NotificationPeriodHelper.class })
public interface ISchedulePayloadMapper
{
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "name", source = "scheduleName"),
        @Mapping(target = "scheduler", source = "schedulerName"),
        @Mapping(target = "notificationPeriod", expression = "java(NotificationPeriodHelper.getConstrainedPeriod(xmlSchedule, notificationFrom, notificationTo))"),
        @Mapping(target = "schedulePeriod", expression = "java(NotificationPeriodHelper.getConstrainedPeriod(xmlSchedule, scheduleFrom, scheduleTo))")
    })
    SchedulePayload map(XmlSchedule xmlSchedule, Lecture lecture);

}
```

Is there any way this can be achieved in another way (i.e. another mapper, decorators, etc.)? How can I pass multiple values (xmlSchedule, lecture) to a mapper?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you can do is create an `@AfterMapping` method to populate those parts manually:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class SchedulePayloadMapper
{
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "name", source = "scheduleName"),
        @Mapping(target = "scheduler", source = "schedulerName"),
        @Mapping(target = "notificationPeriod", expression = "java(NotificationPeriodHelper.getConstrainedPeriod(xmlSchedule, notificationFrom, notificationTo))"),
        @Mapping(target = "schedulePeriod", expression = "java(NotificationPeriodHelper.getConstrainedPeriod(xmlSchedule, scheduleFrom, scheduleTo))")
    })
    public abstract SchedulePayload map(XmlSchedule xmlSchedule, Lecture lecture);

    @AfterMapping
    protected void addPeriods(@MappingTarget SchedulePayload result, XmlSchedule xmlSchedule, Lecture lecture) {
        result.setNotificationPeriod(..);
        result.setSchedulePeriod(..);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can place the `@AfterMapping` method in another class that is referenced in `@Mapper(uses = ..)` or you can use a Decorator (using the mechanisms MapStruct provides, or of your dependency injection framework if you use one).

Comment: `@AfterMapping` seems a clean approach! Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to handle immutable objects?

Comment: @RobertGabriel since the latest (1.3.0.Beta1) MapStruct can use Builders to map into Immutable objects. In the answer of this question, this would mean that you can have the builder for `SchedulePayload` in the `@AfterMapping`

Comment: Yes, you are right. A colleague told me the same thing yesterday. :)

Comment: Note when using the builder pattern in your objects, the `@MappingTarget` should be of type `YourBuilder` instead of your response type!

Comment: Once you use @AfterMapping you dont need these lines anymore:

@Mapping(target = "notificationPeriod", expression = "java(NotificationPeriodHelper.getConstrainedPeriod(xmlSchedule, notificationFrom, notificationTo))"),
        @Mapping(target = "schedulePeriod", expression = "java(NotificationPeriodHelper.getConstrainedPeriod(xmlSchedule, scheduleFrom, scheduleTo))")
    })