# Mapstruct map one field to multiple target fields and vice versa

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

I've referred the question [Map multiple source fields to same type target fields with Mapstruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705417/map-multiple-source-fields-to-same-type-target-fields-with-mapstruct) but it doesn't help

My rest resource classes are like below

```
class Base {
//fields
//getters and setters
}

Class A extends Base{
List<String> emailAdddress;
//other fields
//getters and setters
}

Class B extends Base{
List<String> devices;
//other fields
//getters and setters
}

Class C extends Base{
List<String> mobileNumbers;
//other fields
//getters and setters
}
```

My entity class is Source, like below:

```
 Class Source {
    String address
    //other fields
    //getters and setters
    }
```

I want to map the address from Source class with emailAdddress or devices or mobileNumbers in my mapper class, I tried using @AfterMapping in the mapper class and also a decorator class but it didnt help.

I've a mapper class like this

```
@Mapper
public abstract class AddressMapper {
     //basic mappings here

public abstract Source toEntity(Base b);
public abstract Base toDomain(Source src);

   @AfterMapping 
   public void setAddressInfo(@MappingTarget Source src, B b) {
        src.setAddress(b.getDevices().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I quite follow what you are trying to do.

However, if you want to map the specific classes (`A`, `B`, `C` you would need to put those in the methods. As MapStruct is an annotation processor and during compilation time it only knows about the `Base` fields in your example. What you can do is something like the following:

```
@Maper
public interface AdressMapper {


    default Source toEntity(Base b) {
        if (b == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (b instanceOf A) {
            toEntity((A) b);
        } else if (b instanceOf B) {
            toEntity((A) b);
        } else if (b instanceOf C) {
            toEntity((C) b);
        } else {
            // Decide what to do
        }
    }

    @Mapping(target = "address", source = "emailAddress")
    Source toEntity(A a);

    @Mapping(target = "address", source = "devices")
    Source toEntity(B b);

    @Mapping(target = "address", source = "mobileNumbers")
    Source toEntity(C c);

    default Base toDomain(Source source) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (condition to match to A) {
            return toDomainA(source);
        } else if (condition to match to B) {
            return toDomainB(source);
        } else if (condition to match to C) {
            return toDomainC(source);
        }
    }

    @Mapping(target = "emailAddress", source = "address")
    A toDomainA(Source source);

    @Mapping(target = "devices", source = "address")
    B toDomainB(Source source);

    @Mapping(target = "mobileNumbers", source = "address")
    C toDomainB(Source source);


    // This method is needed so MapStruct knows how to map from List<String> into String
    static <T> String listToString(List<T> list) {
        if (list == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return list.toString();
    }

    // This method is needed so MapStruct know hot to map from String into List<String>
    static List<String> fromListToString(String string) {
        if (string == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Perform your own conversion
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. Will other common fields of Base and Source get mapped? Or do i need to specify them in @Mappings{}?

Comment: Yes they will get automatically mapped